# Watch active channels from remote machine into Asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk

We would like to remotely monitor an Asterisk system for a conference call system managed from web frontend. We can get the terminated calls from the CDR table, and we know that it is possible to execute some [CLI commands](http://wiki.kolmisoft.com/index.php/Watch_active_calls/channels_in_Asterisk_server_from_CLI) to locally monitor the active channels, but is it possible to get that information from a remote machine running PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure. try http://marcelog.github.com/PAMI its an asterisk manager interface that will allow you to do anything ami does

Comment: we'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: This is a ncie project! ... all we need now is to upgrade our CentOS to support PHP 5.3+ :/

Comment: yes, it requires namespaces and this is specifically in php since 5.3 :( other than that, thanks :) i hope you enjoy it. do not hesitate to send any feedback and critics so it can be improved :)

Comment: we can not upgrade our PHP to 5.3 for this project or use a tier server to host PAMI, so we had to find another solution. It is not as complete as this suggested one, but it works. Cheers!